# Chrome Extension Extending Hosts Entries

Tags: google-chrome, hosts

working on multiple servers like production, pre production, development and other types of servers I come across a problem. I am tired of changing my hosts entries all the time and I thought. What if chrome had an extension where I could put my "hostname" and sub menu with ips to resolve.

Is there a plugin for this one, or I would need to create my own?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution, hope it helps you guys - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hostadmin/oklkidkfohahankieehkeenbillligdn